# Change font color of the subtitle in ioslides' cover

Tags: html, css, ioslides

I would like to change the color of the subtitle in my ioslides very first slide (the cover). I managed to change the color, size, etc of the title, as well as the Author and Date.

However, I do not know how to deal with the subtitle. This is my YAML:

```
---
title: "My title"
subtitle: "How can I change the color of the subtitle"
author: "Mario Modesto-Mata"
date: "18 février 2019"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: estilos.css
    smaller: yes
    transition: slower
    widescreen: no
---
```

This CSS is for author and date:

```
slides > slide.title-slide p {
  color: red;
}
```

And this for the title:

```
slides > slide.title-slide hgroup h1 {  color: red;
  font-size: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 10;
}
```

What about the subtitle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve by myself. By selecting `h2` in the `slide.title-slide` we can modify whatever we need.

```
slides > slide.title-slide hgroup h2 {  
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 10;
}
```